# Desconectar Usuário Logado com OAuth Facebook, Google e Twitter

Tags: oauth2, oauth

Quando o usuário pedir para se desconectar da minha aplicação de umas dessas redes sociais:  `Facebook`, `Google` ou `Twitter`, é necessário enviar algum tipo de requisição até API?

Ou posso simplesmente marcar uma flag como desconectado em minha base de dados?